# jQuery .load() but exclude script tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I am using the following jQuery to load in 5 pages into the current page

```
$('.main').load('main.cfm');
$('.bu1').load('bu1.cfm');
$('.bu2').load('bu2.cfm');
$('.bu3').load('bu3.cfm');
$('.bu4').load('bu4.cfm');
```

But each `.cfm` has the following `script` tags in them

```
            <script src="js/jquery.speedometer.js"></script> 
            <script src="js/jquery.jqcanvas-modified.js"></script> 
            <script src="js//excanvas-modified.js"></script> 
            <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#MDTQ').speedometer({
                    backgroundImage: "url(speedo/background-r.png)",
                    maximum: 15,
                    scale: 15,
                    suffix: ''
                });

                $('.changeSpeedometer').click(function(){
                    $('#MDTQ').speedometer({ percentage: $('.speedometer').val() || 0 });
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Is there a way to remove  the below from the pages below whilst being loaded?

```
$('.bu1').load('bu1.cfm');
$('.bu2').load('bu2.cfm');
$('.bu3').load('bu3.cfm');
$('.bu4').load('bu4.cfm');
```

Thanks

Comment: See the section on **script execution**: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @JasonP the `script` tags are inside the body of each page not head

Answer (score 5):

As load is a shortcut for $.get with the convenience of automagically inserting the content for you, you can use that and filter out the script tags before inserting the content yourself:

```
$.get('bu1.cfm', function(html) {
     var markup = $($.trim(html));
     markup.find('script').remove();

     $('.bu1').html(markup);
});
```

EDIT:

to filter by src:

```
$.get('bu1.cfm', function(html) {
     var markup = $($.trim(html));
     $('script[src]', markup).remove();
     $('.bu1').html(markup);
});
```

Comment: @DonaldSutherland - I wrote the selector wrong, maybe it works now ?

Comment: just getting back `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:[entire html page]`

Comment: Made some changes, try that !

Answer (score 1):

use `$.get` with the relatively new `$.parseHTML` method.

```
$.get('bu1.cfm', function(html) {
    var markup = $.parseHTML(html);
    $('#bu1').html(markup);
});
```

by default `$.parseHTML` will remove any script tags within the markup.

If you instead want to only remove scripts that have a src attribute, use the 2nd attribute then filter the results.

```
$.get('bu1.cfm', function(html) {
    var markup = $($.parseHTML(html,true));
    var scripts = markup.find("script").addBack().filter("script");
    scripts.filter("[src]").remove();
    $('#bu1').html(markup).append(scripts);

});
```

Comment: Is there a way to target the files with the `src` in them as I have script files with jquery in them i need

Comment: Yes, use the second parameter, then filter them down similar to how adeneo's answer does.

Comment: the `true` you have in the first line throws me an error `SyntaxError: missing formal parameter`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if using a regexp might be a consideration:
Note: I used a div with a specific id instead of a class to test on. Also, my test file was a complete html document. I've not worked with cfm before, but perhaps the concept is the same.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "yourfile.cfm", 
        dataType: "html",    
        error:function() { alert("error") },
        success:  function(data) {
            $("#main").html(data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\w\W]*?<\/script>/g,""));
        }});
});
```