# Load external page with different jQuery version

Tags: jquery, versions

Is it possible to load another page with a different jQuery version?

I have an HTML page with a membership system that uses jQuery 2.1.3 and am trying to load an external PHP page with a scroller effect that uses jQuery 1.10.3.

The PHP page works fine on its own, but when I try load it using GET, LOAD,  methods I get these errors:

```
TypeError: $.widget is not a function jq.js line 2 > eval:1:40
TypeError: $(...).smoothTouchScroll is not a function
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "load"? Include at the PHP level or $.get/$.load

Comment: What is the "loading" method? Is the page included server side, through an ajax call or just an iframe?

Comment: display the contents of the external php page in a DIV.

Comment: @valepu - the latest code i tried was    $("#res").load("scroller.php");

Comment: That's nothing to do with jq version but issue comes from on new page, you aren't including relevant plugins EDIT: it appears you mean you are loading page using ajax request, so you shouldn't include a new jq version in loaded page, it removes previous plugin methods. You should instead use this method and exclude specifically jq 1.10.3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/17860548/1414562

Comment: @a. wolff  i think i understand that the latest jq tag supercedes the previous, but tried removing jq 1.10.3 tag from my external page and got same error.   also that page uses custom js and removing it makes the scroll effect not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand it, issue comes from your new loaded page include an other jq version, you should exclude it using:

```
$.get('scroller.php', function(html) {
     var markup = $($.trim(html));
     $('script[src*="1.10.3"]', markup).remove();
     $('#res').html(markup);
});
```

Comment: tried this and got same errors.  appreciate ur response.

Comment: oh wow, i tried removing the 1.10.3 tag again from the external page and it works now !  no errors.  huh, maybe it was cached or something when i tried it the first time..  so in principle your answer is correct (though i am removing the tag entirely from the external page instead of "removing" it using this method.)  i will experiment some more tonight and may mark this as the answer , thx

Comment: excluding the 2nd jquery was indeed the solution, no matter how its done.

Answer (score 2):

`$.widget` - Is a part of [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/). You just need to add this library to your page. jQuery version does not matter.